# Trim text file to first column with java

Tags: java, string, char, substring, trim

Well, i've got this list of IP's.

```
193.137.150.5              368 ms                DANIEL-PC             
193.137.150.7              95 ms                 N/A                   
193.137.150.13             37 ms                 N/A                   
193.137.150.17             33 ms                 N/A                   
193.137.150.24             238 ms                N/A                   
193.137.150.38             74 ms                 DUARTE-PC             
193.137.150.41             26 ms                 N/A                   
193.137.150.52             176 ms                N/A
```

I wanted to use java to remove only the IP's from the list.

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class trim{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String s;
        char c;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (in.hasNextLine()){
            s = in.nextLine();
            c = s.charAt(i);
            while (c != ' '){
                System.out.print(c);
                i++;
                c = s.charAt(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop you never zero out `i`. This means your offset will be wrong for each line after the first.

```
    while (in.hasNextLine()){
        s = in.nextLine();
        c = s.charAt(i);
        while (c != ' '){
            System.out.print(c);
            i++;
            c = s.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        i = 0; // Finished with this line
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually remembered to do that and completely forgot it somewhere in between.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (in.hasNextLine()){
    s = in.nextLine();
    String[] arr = s.split(" "); // if delimeter is whitespace use s.split("\\s+")  
    System.out.println(arr[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply split your Strings once and print the second part

```
while (in.hasNextLine()){
    s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s.split(" ", 1)[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not reinitializing i,

```
    while (in.hasNextLine()){
        s = in.nextLine();
        // reset i so you start reading at line begin
        i = 0;
        c = s.charAt(i);
        while (c != ' '){
            System.out.print(c);
            i++;
            c = s.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

That being said, there are easier methods, eg using `String.split()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinit i = 0.
You can do it after the nextLine call

```
    s = in.nextLine();
    i = 0;
```